# after running crao -n react-app, how do i implement routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm a noobie at react and internet isn't always available to me, so i've been using create-react-app-offline, but now i want to make a multi-page app with routing and i'm stuck. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [Quick Start](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) guide from React Router, and download the rest of the documentation. While you have internet access, try to install the necessary packages needed from npm or yarn